# Getting values from a Django JSONField

Tags: django

I'm trying to retrieve values from a JSONField in my model, but i'm getting an error:

'Api' object has no attribute 'openapi_spec__info__title'

```
class Api(models.Model):
''' Model to hold infomation on the API '''

# JSONB field to hold the OpenAPI spec
openapi_spec = JSONField()

# Derive product name from the OpenAPI spec, since it's a mandatory field
def _get_product_name(self):
    return self.openapi_spec__info__title
product_name = property(_get_product_name)
```

According to the Django docs '__' is the correct way to filter on the JSON data, but maybe it's not the correct way to access it?

```
{"info": {"title": "Test API", "version": "1.0.0"}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Double-underscore syntax is only valid in things like filters and sorting, whether you're dealing with a JSON field or a traditional cross-table join.

The field gives you a dictionary. You use normal dictionary syntax from that point on.

```
self.openapi_spec['info']['title']
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! About the only damn thing I didn't try :-)